# Translation tag is not working in templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

i tried to change the content of the open source in the development environment.

Example . : i need to change the line in the main page. " what`s new n django com......?"

```
{% block content %}<BR/>
    <h1>{% trans "What's new in Django community blogs? %}</h1><BR/>
    {% autopaginate posts 15 %}<BR/>
    {% for post in posts %}<BR/>
        <div class="post"><BR/>
            {% post_details post %}<BR/>
        </div><BR/>
    {% endfor %}<BR/>
```

after changing the line like this

```
{% block content %}<BR/>
    <h1>{% trans "Community blog sites %}</h1><BR/>
    {% autopaginate posts 15 %}<BR/>
    {% for post in posts %}<BR/>
        <div class="post"><BR/>
            {% post_details post %}<BR/>
        </div><BR/>
    {% endfor %}<BR/>
```

I hit the refresh button its not changing .. why ?

Comment: `{% trans "Community blog sites" %}` you didn't close "".

Comment: Have you translated the string ? using django-rosetta or so ? Because when you do `{% trans "Community blog sites" %}` you only mark the text as translated string but if you don't make the translations Django won't do it for you, and also depends on the active language, if the string is in english and the active language is english Django won't translate anything

Comment: So how to change then @Liarez

Comment: I know that django-rosetta is not neccesary to do translations, you can do it just with django but I'm not used to that, here is some info [Django Translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/) . If you want I can make an answer about how to do it with rosetta, you have some configuration to do, but you can do the translation via web, using django you have to modify file by file (I think)

Comment: OK can you look into my another question there i attached image of my project .. Please @Liarez

Comment: Did u saw that @Liarez

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the string in `trans` both times...

```
 <h1>{% trans "Community blog sites" %}</h1><BR/>
                                   ^ there
```

Comment: after closing " also .. No changes in the main page . Its still showing same

Comment: And also can you please guide me how to change SITE_NAME in [django-planet](https://github.com/matagus/django-planet/tree/master/planet/templates)

Comment: SITE_NAME i changed in admin page .. But when i making some changes in the above . After hitting refresh Django won`t update .. I don`t know why .. Can you please guide me

Comment: Do you have python pip installed ?

Comment: yes @Liarez why nobody understand what i am trying to say .. When i change something in the base.html its suppose to come when i hitting refresh in the local server . But again its showing old one only ,.,

Comment: ?? you write some new text in base.html, refresh the page and you don't see that text ?